# Jquery - Append value to Paragraph

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 4 groups of data that are tied to a click-bind event. I'm trying to add the value from a hidden field contained within each group to a paragraph later in the page, so that when the checkbox is clicked from one or more groups of data, the value from the hidden field displays within the paragraph area.

I'd also like to get it so that when the checkbox is unclicked, it removes the value from the paragraph, but for now I'm just trying to get the value to display when the checkbox is clicked.

Here's what I've tried:

This is the hidden field within the group of data that stores the value:

```
<input id="servicename_<?php echo $i;?>" name="servicename_<?php echo $i;?>"
type="hidden" value="<?php echo $service->PRODUCT;?>"></input>
```

This is the click-bind event:

```
$('input[id^=ckNow_]').each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click',function(){
      if($(this).prop('checked'))
        {

var servicename = '#servicename_'+$(this).attr('value').split("_");

ServiceName += servicename;

$('#lblServiceName').append($(ServiceName));
```

EDIT to add the checkbox that is within each group:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckNow_<?php echo $i;?>" name="ckNow[<?php echo $i;?>]">
</input>
```

And then the paragraph text:

```
<p id="lblServiceName">Service Name
<input type="hidden" id="servicename" value="0"></input>
</p>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? All responses are very appreciated and I'm completely open to any and all suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: are there multiple checkboxes  and paragraphs? if so when a checkbox is checked how do you know which paragraph has to be edited

Comment: There are multiple checkboxes and one paragraph.

Comment: will you be able to share the complete generated html - if possible create a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dKAD4/1/

Comment: if multiple checboxes are checked then what should happen?

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gandjyar/cxpKa/ If multiple checkboxes are checked, each value should populate in the paragraph area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<p id="lblServiceName">Service Name
    <span></span>
    <input type="hidden" id="servicename" value="0"></input>
</p>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $checks = $('.group-data input[name^="ckNow["]').change(function () {
        var vals = $checks.filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return $(this).closest('.group-data').find('input[id^=servicename_]').val()
        }).get();
        $('#lblServiceName span').text(vals.join(', '))
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ubtvP/)